# How can I upload the xml file to google cse in autocompletion section?

Tags: xml, autocomplete, search-engine

I have an xml file such as https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/queries in Adding and Removing Autocompletion Terms section. But i can't upload it to google cse control panel autocompletion section, because I get an error messeage: it can't upload successfully. Why?

```html
<Autocompletions>
  <Autocompletion term="cake" type="1" language=""/>
  <Autocompletion term="strawberry.*" type="2" match="2" language=""/>
  <Autocompletion term="vanilla" type="2" language=""/>
  <Autocompletion term="apple" type="3" language="">
    <Promotion id="1" queries="dessert" title="Apple pie for dessert!" url="http://www.example.com/applepieforsale"
        start_date="" end_date="" image_url=""  description="Apple pie is the best dessert ever!"/>
    <Promotion id="2" queries="apple" title="Buy Apple pie" url="http://www.example.com/applepieforsale"
        start_date="" end_date="" image_url="" description="We stock the best apple pie in the world, right here."/>
  </Autocompletion>
</Autocompletions>
```

Comment: When I upload the xml file, then get an error message: File upload failed.